# Vaadin Flow dark mode Dialog

Tags: css, dialog, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

How can i set my dialog theme from light to dark?
When i'm doing

```
dialog.setAttribute("theme", Lumo.DARK);
```

then background under dialog have solid colour and i can't see what is benath it like in normal theme. I changed dialog theme on the official vaadin page and there isthis same problem. I`m using Vaadin 14.7.6.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no out-of-the-box support for a dark variant for Dialog specifically. You can set the whole application to use the dark theme, though.

If you only want a dark themed Dialog, you need to do what you already did, but override the background color of the `<vaadin-dialog-overlay>` element.

Comment: oh thanks i didnt know that i can change theme for whole app, i was just setting per layout. So ijust set dark mode for AppLayout and then everything was drawing in rihjt colours but dialogs was still in default. now everthing is working fine.